# Cassandra Collection as Blob

Tags: cassandra, cql

Is there a way to store a collection as a blob in Cassandra without having to convert it to text? It appears to not be possible. Cassandra offers [blob conversion functions](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/blob_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_cgg_nf5_yj__blob-conversion-functions) that claim to support any of the native non blob types.

> For every native, nonblob type supported by CQL, the typeAsBlob function takes a argument of type type and returns it as a blob.

It is understandable that this syntax could get complicated for collections, if the collection type *and* member type were required; e.g. `uuidSetAsText`.

### Example

**Column Family**

```
> create table blob_test (id text primary key, blob_field blob);
```

**`INSERT` text as blob**

```
> INSERT INTO blob_test (id, blob_field) VALUES ( '5', textAsBlob('test blob text') );
> select * from blob_test ;

 id | blob_field
----+--------------------------------
  5 | 0x7465737420626c6f622074657874
```

**`INSERT` set as blob**

```
> INSERT INTO blob_test (id, blob_field) VALUES ( '6', setAsBlob({'1', '2', '3'}) );
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown function setasblob called"

> INSERT INTO blob_test (id, blob_field) VALUES ( '6', textSetAsBlob({'1', '2', '3'}) );
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown function textsetasblob called"

> INSERT INTO blob_test (id, blob_field) VALUES ( '6', collectionAsBlob({'1', '2', '3'}) );
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown function collectionasblob called"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apache documentation is a bit more informative than the DataStax docs. Native-type and collection-type are two separate groups of types. "native" does not simply mean any type that is natively supported by CQL.

From the [Cassandra Apache docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#types):

```
<type> ::= <native-type>
         | <collection-type>
         | <tuple-type>
         | <string>       // Used for custom types. The fully-qualified name of a JAVA class

<native-type> ::= ascii
                | bigint
                | blob
                | boolean
                | counter
                | decimal
                | double
                | float
                | inet
                | int
                | text
                | timestamp
                | timeuuid
                | uuid
                | varchar
                | varint

<collection-type> ::= list '<' <native-type> '>'
                    | set  '<' <native-type> '>'
                    | map  '<' <native-type> ',' <native-type> '>'
<tuple-type> ::= tuple '<' <type> (',' <type>)* '>'
```

A work around is to translate the collection to text, and then utilize blob functions.

```
> INSERT INTO blob_test (id, blob_field) VALUES ( '6', textAsBlob('{"1", "2", "3"}') );
```

In my case, I just avoided blob and added a column for each type I needed to support.